# How to write my python code so that it sums the numbers from a .txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Yeah so I have been working on this for hours and I can't get it to work. My code is as follows:

```py
numbers_file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
#print(numbers_file.read())
for line in numbers_file():
    sum(line)
```

I left the `#print(numbers_file.read())` in there just to show my thinking.

Any input on how I can do this would be very nice, Thanks.

Comment: what does `sum(line)` do?

Comment: What does the file look like? You will need to cast the strings into integers or floats at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
print(sum(map(float, open('numbers.txt').read().split())))
```

or

```
import pathlib
import math
print(math.fsum(map(float, pathlib.Path('numbers.txt').read_text().split())))
```

Both
[TextIOWrapper.read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read)
and
[Path.read_text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)
return the contents of the file as a string.
[str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=string%20split#str.split) split the string according to any whitespace.
[map](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) applies a function
[float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float#float)
to every word.
[sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) computes the total. The second version is more pedantic. It closes the file and uses an
accurate floating point sum.

Comment: May I also suggest using `.readlines()` instead of `.read().split()`?

Comment: @iteratedwalls Thanks. I am not sure. `.read().split()` also works for several numbers in one line.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that will work as long as the file contains *only* numbers (integers or floats), separated by whitespace (including newlines). (It's good practice to open files with a context manager, i.e., the `with ... as` part, as it closes the file automatically.)

```py
total = 0

with open('numbers.txt', mode='r') as numbers_file:
    for number in numbers_file.read().split():
        total += float(number)

print(total)
```